# Windows Server 2008 R2 - IIS7.5 - Web site permissions

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7.5

Why when I remove the MACHINENAME\Users group permission set from a websites physical folder and and grant a similar permission set to MACHINENAME\IIS_IUSRS group my website will not start.

Why do I have to grant Read & Execute, List folder contents and Read to the MACHINENAME\Users group physical website folder?

Answer (score 1):

Windows Authentication was enabled on website.  Clients who visited the intranet site were granted access via MACHINENAME\Users