# IIS 7.5 folder and web site permissions

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, permissions, iis-7.5

**Situation:**

- test website created in IIS server manager

  - basic settings/connect as: Application user
  - authentication/anonymous authentication/edit: application pool identity
- physical path has "IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool" read and execute, list folder contents and read permissions (plus administrators/system with inherited full control)

  - contains a single file, index.html (plus generated web.config with the above settings)

**Errors:**

- HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
- Config Error Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions

**Questions:**

- how do I make it work with app identity? (got it to work using using iusr both under anonymous auth and with rx permission on the physical folder)
- am I doing it wrong or this is indeed the best practice as most resources I've found seem to suggest?

I'd also really appreciate **any good tutorials** on the "basics" of IIS 7.5 - I have been unable to find answers to this specific questions on learn.iis.net and several other sites and generally found the resources available there very fragmented.

*Related:* [IIS 7.5 web site directory permisions](https://serverfault.com/questions/305408/iis-7-5-web-site-directory-permisions), [Windows Server 2008 R2 - IIS7.5 - Web site permissions](https://serverfault.com/questions/131951/windows-server-2008-r2-iis7-5-web-site-permissions)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you've created the website using the usual IIS7.5 out-of-the-box defaults then your "test website" will have had an application pool created for it as well.

The default identity that the site will execute requests as is `ApplicationPoolIdentity`. `ApplicationPoolIdentity` is a special synthesised account that is created on the fly and represents the identity of your site's application pool.

You state:

> physical path has "IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool" read and execute

This would explain why you're getting the `500.19` error. Unless you assigned the site to the "DefaultAppPool" application pool this permission won't be doing anything useful.

You need to assign the `ApplicationPoolIdentity` of the site (at least) read and execute permissions. To do this execute the following from the command line:

```
icacls <path_to_site> /grant "IIS APPPOOL\<app_pool_name>"(CI)(OI)(M)
```

Where `<app_pool_name>` is the name of the application pool that was created for your test site. You can find its name by executing:

```
appcmd list app /site.name:"<your site name>"
```

This will return something like and displays the name of your site's application pool (which `ApplicationPoolIdentity` is named after:

```
APP "test site/" (applicationPool:test site)
```

Comment: I was indeed using ASP.NET v4.0 application pool, and using IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0 did the trick - had no idea it was a "dynamic" user name. tyvm, do you happen to know of a good tutorial site where I can read more about IIS basics?

Comment: @Razor - Glad that helped :). iis.net is as good as any but does assume some basic familiarity with IIS configuration. I'd recommend grabbing a copy of the Microsoft IIS 7 Resource kit book which would give you a good grounding to build from and makes navigating the iis.net reference material a bit easier.